# CSS - Move grid item on screen resize

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm learning grid and am a bit stuck.  I've created a site that has a full width header, side by side "sidebar" / "main section" and a full width footer.  What I'm trying to achieve is that when the screen is resized smaller (or viewed on a small screen device), the "main section" falls below the "sidebar" instead of being side by side with it.

I've looked into and attempted auto-fill, minmax on the column widths but I can't get it to work and I feel I'm missing something fundamental or am setting the grid up wrong which would stop that from working.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Any assistance greatly appreciated!

The grid css below is without any attempt to move the section:

```
.grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 10px solid #14a76c;
  display: grid;

     grid-template: 
      "header header header" 3fr
      "side main main" 3fr
      "footer footer footer" .5fr
      "footer2 footer2 footer2" .5fr
         
       / 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     
  grid-gap: 5px, 5px; 
     
  margin-top: 40px; 
}

.grid-item {

  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 4px solid #ff652f;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item-1 {
grid-area: header; 
}
.item-2 {
grid-area: side;
}
.item-3 {
grid-area: main;
}
.item-4 {
grid-area: footer;
}
.item-5 {
grid-area: footer2;
}
```

Comment: Use [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @ciekals11 ..isn't that just "bodging" it though and grid should be able to accomplish what I'm trying to achieve?  I'm trying to learn how to do it the "right" way :) - unless I'm completey missing something, which may be the case!

Comment: No, media queries are an **essential** part of web layout. Css-Grid is not **magic**....it does what you tell it and media queries are how you do that.

Comment: @paulie_D ok, could you advise on what properties I should be changing with the media query to get the result I stated?  cheers

EDIT: I've cracked it, in the media query I've changed the grid-template-areas and grid-template-columns properties...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a media query to change the grid-template when the screen width becomes smaller than a cutoff point

```
/* append this to above code */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template: /* Define a new grid-template to be used when width<=640px */;
  }
}
```